# Не работает require

Tags: javascript

node -v (v18.14.2).
Использую этот код в webpack.config.js для того, чтобы require работало в js файле. Ибо пишет, что require undefined...

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

В консоли выдаёт ошибку:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "module". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
Как это пофиксить? Не могу понять..